# Why will Windows XP not start without a reboot?

Tags: boot, windows-xp

I have a computer with only Windows XP installed. When I turn on the computer, I get this message:

```
Reboot and Select proper Boot device
or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key
```

If I press CTRL+ALT+DEL, it reboots and then boots into Windows XP. I can't find any way to directly go to Windows XP without first rebooting at this screen. How can I fix this?

Comment: But this error appears every single time I boot Windows XP.

Comment: Does it appear when you Restart from within XP?

Comment: No it doesn't when I restart from XP.

Comment: If you power-on and then go to BIOS, does the drive appear therein and in the boot order? If you have any option to select the boot menu at startup, does it appear and boot if you manually select the boot drive from the boot menu?

Comment: The drive appears at the first option, CD appears second, and both also appear when using F11 to display the boot menu.

Comment: Make and model of PC?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that this is a CMOS battery fault. If you are still running Windows XP there is a good chance that the system is up to 15 years old and batteries are only likely to run for 5 to 10 years.

On first boot the CMOS is invalid and randomised due to a dead battery, and it is rewritten after booting. This rewrite of defaults may not, depending on firmware, actually be applied until after a reboot.

First replace the battery.